# How to store an image with Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

**From my form I try to save an image for the user's profile**, I really don't understand why I receive the following validation error.

[image: Form]

In the form I am indicating the following: **(enctype, input of type file)**

```
<div class="row">  
    
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.users.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
   
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Perfil</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('status_id', 'Estado') !!}
                    {!! Form::select('status_id', $status, null, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'id' => 'status_id', 'style' => 'width:100%;']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">                 
                    <label for="user_photo">Imagen de Perfil</label>
                    <input type="file" id="user_photo" name="user_photo">
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}  
</div>
```

In my controller in the **store method I try to store the image** with the other user fields as follows:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
                //  Transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();

                 // Validar el formulario
                 $data = $request->validate([
                    'name'      => 'required|string|max:255',
                    'email'     => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',     
                    'user_photo' => 'required|file',                          
                ]);
                
                // Generar una contraseña
                $data['password'] = str_random(8);
             
                // Creamos el usuario 
                dd($request->all());  
                if (request()->hasFile('user_photo')) {
                    $file = request()->file('user_photo')->store('public');                  
                    $user = new User;   
                    $user->name         = $request->get('name');
                    $user->surname      = $request->get('surname');
                    $user->nickname     = $request->get('nickname');
                    $user->email        = $request->get('email');        
                    $user->password     = $request->get('password');
                    $user->gender       = $request->get('gender');  
                    $user->address      = $request->get('address');
                    $user->postcode     = $request->get('postcode');  
                    $user->city         = $request->get('city');
                    $user->province     = $request->get('province');
                    $user->phone        = $request->get('phone');   
                    $user->user_photo   = $file;
                    $user->save();
                    
                // Enviamos el email
                UserWasCreated::dispatch($user, $data['password']);
              
                }else{
                     return 'no se recibio nada';
                }
    }
```

In my complete form the necessary fields to complete the user profile and also select an image, **if I click the create button as you can see, it throws a required field validation error, when I have already selected an image.**
**One more observation if I comment the validation of user: photo as a required field, skip the method esle: nothing was received**.

If they are fixed make an inspection with ** dd ($ request-> all ()); ** to my method and this is the result.

```
array:15 [
  "_token" => "gRxLpp5fSjPo8aE0XhKCPYJzAlUuqoV6hjhxkvv7"
  "name" => "aa"
  "surname" => null
  "gender" => null
  "email" => "ale@gmail.com"
  "nickname" => null
  "birthdate" => null
  "password" => null
  "password_confirmation" => null
  "status_id" => "1"
  "phone" => null
  "address" => null
  "postcode" => null
  "city" => null
  "province" => null
]
```

The user_photo field is missing.

**I don't understand what is happening?**.
I need someone to give me a hand with this that I'm dealing with a few days ago
**Does the project cloned from my repository have something to do with it?** It doesn't occur because my store method is not working.

Comment: Make validation outside `DB::beginTransaction();` you get this error after submit (post request)?

Comment: @STA no that is not the problem comment this  DB::beginTransaction(); and anyway I get to the else of the method did not receive anything